# ReactJS - load the data before rendering the component

Tags: reactjs

In the ReactJS, I am changing the route to some new one with an "id", then based on this "id", I must call an API and fetch data.

I have used the API call in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` and tried `setState()` to have my data in the state. but they didn't work in my case.

The problem is in the `render()` part when I want to use my data (from state), the data is not there because the API call takes some time to update the state.

Here is my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    api.get(id).then((response) => {
     this.setState({response,});
  });
```

With this approach, I don't have the data when I want it (render method), it will eventually be in the state but too late!

How can I change my approach to fix the loading problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you are doing it, you could validate the response state object in your render method, and if it is null/empty, then return `<div>Loading...</div>`.

When your state is then updated based on the response, the component will automagically re-render. This time, the object will be populated and you can return your component HTML.

e.g.

```
render(){

    if (!this.state.response){
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return (
        <div>Proper Stuff</div>
    );
}
```

**Edit** On a site note, if you set the initial state in the constructor, you can make sure the object isn't empty, but just has null/empty values. This could also help depending what your `render` method is doing, e.g.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        response: {...}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your render code should be

```
render(){
 return({this.state.response?
          <div> Render your component here</div>: 
          <div> Loading ... </div>});
}
```

This way your component would not render till it has the data and show `Loading ...` text instead.